# Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../" - deploy Vue Vite on Netlify

Tags: vue.js, deployment, vuejs3, vite, netlify

I am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

I want to deploy the frontend of my app on Netlify, but I keep getting this error. What are those relative references? Does it have something to do with that my vue file is not in root directory, but in frontend/vue folder?

[image]

When I change base directory to /frontend/ I get 404 error: [image]

Do I have to add something for example in public _redirects folder? I know that using React I had to add `/* /index.html 200`. I added that here, but it didn't help.

This is my folder structure:

[image]

Comment: You need to build your app for it to run in production, and I see you have no build command.  Probably `yarn build` or `npm run build` depending on what's in your package.json.  You'll also need to set the "Publish directory", usually `dist` by default which is where all your build files end up.